# Change 'Key Usage' of a certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to change the 'Key Usage' property of an existing ssl certificate of a web site? Our goal is to host a web service so that a third party can integrate with our solution, and their requirement is that our ssl certificate has 'Data Encipherment' in the 'Key usage' field. Currently our ssl for the site doesn't. Trying to see if it is as simple as somehow editing existing certificate without having to buy a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once the certificate is issued and signed, you can't change anything in it.